# Replace method with array value

Tags: javascript

I am using a random function to randomly slide between 4 swiper sliders, here is my code :

```
var swipers = [swiper1, swiper2, swiper3, swiper4];
setInterval(function(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    swipers[rand].slideNext();
    }, 3000);
}
```

How should i proceed if i wanted to randomize between slideNext() and slidePrev() ? I tried many things like this :

```
var direction = ['slideNext()', 'slidePrev()'];
var swipers = [swiper1, swiper2, swiper3, swiper4];
setInterval(function(){
   var randx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
   var randy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
   swipers[randx].direction[randy];
}, 3000);
```

But it's not working, probably for obvious reasons, but please help me understand why it's not working. And how i could possibly achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the method name in the arrays, without parentheses. Then use it to index the object, and call the result of that.

You should also use `<arrayname>.length` rather than hard-coding the lengths when you get the random index, so you don't have to change it if you add more swipers or directions.

```
var direction = ['slideNext', 'slidePrev'];
var swipers = [swiper1, swiper2, swiper3, swiper4];
setInterval(function(){
   var randx = Math.floor(Math.random() * swipers.length);
   var randy = Math.floor(Math.random() * direction.length);
   swipers[randx][direction[randy]]();
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close! Just change how you're setting the direction and I think you got it:

```
swipers[randx][direction[randy]]();
```

Also remove the parenthesis from your array and just leave the function names there.